# How do I deal with the summations correctly whose upper or lower bounds are symbolic?

Tags: symbolic, summation

I'm new to Wolfram Mathematica and I want to calculate the expression of `s` (with respect to `n`) to get the same result as this python code.

```py
s = 0
for i in [1..n]:  # iterate i from 1 to n
    for j in [1..n]:
        for k in [i..j]:  # When i > j, skip it.
            s += 1
```

For example, when `n = 10`, it should be $220$ in fact.

I tried this code in Mathematica:

```
Sum[1, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, i, j}]
```

which tells me that the answer is $n^2$, not corresponding to my expectation.

I have found that Mathematica can deal with such summation whose upper bound is less than its lower bound correctly, when the bounds are constants (output $0$ as answer), but when there's a symbolic bound, the result will be something like this:

```
Sum[1, {i, j, k}]
```

> `1 - j + k`

When $j > k + 1$, it comes with a negative value. I guess this is the reason for the previous wrong output.

I searched and learnt that I should set `GenerateConditions` to `True` for the expression with correct conditions. So I tried this code:

```
Sum[Sum[1, {k, i, j}, GenerateConditions -> True], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
```

But I got this (copied from MMA online):

```
ConditionalExpression[Piecewise[{{1, n == 1}}, 0], n <= 1]
```

It doesn't tell what should be when $n > 1$. I'm really puzzled now, and I want to know how to handle this case properly or what the keywords I could search with?

Comment: The documentation is surprisingly unclear on the expected behaviour of `Sum` when the first limit is larger than the second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is via `Boole`:

```
Sum[Boole[i <= k], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, i, j}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

...which produces: $$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{6} \left(n^3+3 n^2+2 n\right) & n\geq 1 \\0 & \text{True}\end{cases}$$

For $n=10$, this gives 220.

Answer (score 8):

No need for making it so complicated:

```
Sum[1, {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, j}, {k, i, j}]
```

> 1/6 n (1 + n) (2 + n)